# PHP directory path using variables

Tags: php, variables

I have the code below that should copy the file index.php to the directory

```
$path="/data/www/vhosts/themacsplash.com/httpdocs/ClipBoy/userfiles/";
$fpath="/data/www/vhosts/themacsplash.com/httpdocs/ClipBoy/userfiles/index.php";
$myFolder = $path . $myUser;
$myFolderP = &myFolder."/"."index.php";
```

I need `$myFolderP` to be set to `$myFolder/index.php` so e.g:

```
/data/www/vhosts/themacsplash.com/httpdocs/ClipBoy/userfiles/will/index.php
```

How would I do this? My current code for `$myFolderP` gives me the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   '.', expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM
>   in
>   /data/www/vhosts/themacsplash.com/httpdocs/ClipBoy/code/index.php
>   on line 94

I'm sure it's an easy fix.

Comment: What exactly is the line that gives that error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must write this

```
$myFolderP = $myFolder."/"."index.php";
```

Instead of this

```
$myFolderP = &myFolder."/"."index.php";
```